# Where can I find datasets with large number of features (100000) but less samples(100-1000)?

Tags: classification, bigdata, dataset

I am working on a dimensionality reduction algorithm for datasets with high feature to sample ratio. I need datasets with around 100000 features or more and 100-1000 samples with class labels to evaluate my algorithm's performance.

Moreover the features should be real valued and not binary like in the Dorothea dataset.

Comment: This question seems more relevant in Open Data community, can you ask there?

Comment: [UCI dataset repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html?format=&task=reg&att=&area=&numAtt=greater100&numIns=100to1000&type=&sort=nameUp&view=table) has a couple of datasets that match your requirements. You could always sample larger wide data sets.

Comment: IOk I will ask it there also I will post the list of all the datasets that I get here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take a dataset that has a large number of features and ignore as much data as you need to get the ratio you desire. E.g. take imagenet, but randomly select 100 samples per class.

Answer (score 2):

If a synthetic dataset is an option, you can create it with sklearn in python:

> **sklearn.datasets.make_classification**
>
> Generate a random n-class classification problem.
> This initially creates clusters of points normally distributed (std=1) about vertices of a 2 * class_sep-sided hypercube, and assigns an equal number of clusters to each class. It introduces interdependence between these features and adds various types of further noise to the data.

Example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
 
n_classes = 5
n_samples = 100*n_classes
n_informative = 100
 
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=n_samples, 
                          n_features=n_features, 
                          n_informative=n_informative,
                          n_classes=n_classes)
```

More:

[sklearn.datasets.make_classification](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html)

Comment: Your method is great, however synthetic dataset is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Scikit-learn have simple data sets in which you may specify the number of features.

```
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=100, centers=2, n_features=100000, random_state=42)
```

For additional information about the statistical properties of this data set check out [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html).